# How do people breathe in the Dredd universe?

Tags: dredd

From what I know about the world of Dredd, the Earth is pretty much either irradiated wasteland or cities.  There are still billions of people living in the megacities taking up all the oxygen, and there are no plants to produce more. It seems eventually the planet would simply run out or dip below sustainable levels.  Was this ever addressed?

Comment: Do the oceans still have phytoplankton? There might be enough oxygen in the world if the oceans still produce tons of it.

Comment: @anaranjada - The Black Atlantic is heavily polluted, to the point that swimming in it will dissolve flesh.

Comment: Based on the fact that you've accepted an answer that has zero references to the Dredd universe, I'm debating whether to tempted to flag this for a transfer to [Earth Science: SE](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) or [Biology:SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Richard  Being new here I'm not exactly sure if there are even rules regarding which answer I could accept. Your answer was good, but unfortunately I can only accept one.  His was an answer I liked because it could be extended to other apocalyptic universes that would have the same issue.

Comment: @deev - You're completely free to choose whichever answer you like as your "accepted" one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The out-of-universe answer is the Dredd universe is a satire of an overpopulated, over-urbanized police state and not intended to make scientific sense.

That said, just how long could billions of people keep breathing if the Earth's oxygen cycle broke down? A long time. The Earth's atmosphere is really, really, really, really big compared to puny humans (though not their machines).

A single human uses [about 550 liters of pure oxygen per day](http://health.howstuffworks.com/human-body/systems/respiratory/question98.htm). Not air, oxygen. At an atmospheric density of about 1.2 g/L that's about 660 g or 0.66 kg per person per day or 240 kg per person per year.

The atmosphere of the Earth weighs about 5.15e18 kg. 3/4 of that is within 11km of the surface, so let's use that: 3.86e18 kg.  How much of that is oxygen? Oxygen is about 21% *by volume* with the rest being nitrogen and 1% miscellaneous that I'll ignore. But we want the percentage of oxygen by mass.

We can use the [density of those gases](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/gas-density-d_158.html) to work out their mass ratios in air. 1.331 g/L for O<sub>2</sub> and 1.205 g/L for air at [normal temperature and pressure](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/stp-standard-ntp-normal-air-d_772.html).

1 liter of air weighs 1.205 g. 21% of the volume is oxygen, so it contributes `0.21 * 1.331 g/L = 0.28g`. Divide them to get the mass-ratio of oxygen: `0.28g / 1.205g = 23%`.

23% of 3.86e18 kg is 8.9e17 kg. That's a decent approximation of how much oxygen is in the atmosphere. Humans can survive as low as 17% oxygen, 6.6e17 kg, so they can safely consume 2.3e17 kg.

How long will it last?

```
2.3e17 kg / 240 kg per person per year = 9.6e14 person-years
```

Lacking a census for the Judge Dredd universe, I'll use 10 billion people or 1e10. They will have 9.6e4 or 96,000 years of breathing what's left in the atmosphere before there is a problem.

The bigger problem will be the build up of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere, we're far more sensitive to too much CO<sub>2</sub> then to too little O<sub>2</sub>. I'll leave that for someone else to work out.

Comment: That is an amazing answer.

Comment: Surely they have some machines consuming oxygen.

Comment: @anaranjada That would require knowing something about how the Dredd universe produces power, and that would require trying to make sense of the Judge Dredd universe (good luck). I think we can safely assume they're not burning fossil fuels anymore to produce power (ie. oxidation) as the required global transportation network has broken down.

Comment: This answer is ... *puts on sunglasses* ... breathtaking. YEAH!

Comment: Nice, an interesting point I never knew about. One thing I wonder, can we assume most of the oxygen-breathing microorganisms are dead too, and if not what share would they take up? I found [this paper](http://bluemoon.ucsd.edu/publications/ralph/5_O2measurements.pdf) which on p. 3 shows the "global oxygen budget" (all the types of processes that either add or subtract oxygen from the atmosphere), looks like even if you took away the "gross primary production" from life on land and sea, but also stopped the removal of oxygen by heterotrophs (plants), it'd still take several thousand years.

Comment: Yes, Hypnosifl brings up a point I forgot about: oxygen is reactive enough that it will go away on its own if the planet has no life. I don't know how long that process takes.

Comment: Nice answer +1. If there's no plant life the CO2 problem is much more immediate

Comment: My issue with this answer is that it demonstrates **zero knowledge of the Dredd universe**. It's a good answer for [Earth Science: SE](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) but inappropriate for here. Still, the mob seem to like it.

Comment: @Schwern - It irks me because this there's no sci-*fi* in your answer. If the OP isn't interested in the fictional element, why bother asking it on a sci-fi website?

Comment: @Richard You're absolutely correct I don't know the Dredd universe well. It's cool, you have that side covered as usual. :) It is appropriate to apply *science* to *science*-fiction to establish baselines to then deviate from and add detail to. "How do people breathe in <future setting with no plants>?"

Comment: @Richard Sci-fi is doing its job when reading it sparks good science questions, and the OP seems happy with the answer. This is rapidly getting meta.

Comment: @Schwern - Except that there palpably are plants. Even the most cursory examination of the Dredd universe shows that there's plenty of plant life about, just less of it than before :-)

Comment: @Richard If there was an answer with details about the Dredd ecosystem that would be awesome! Since we don't know what's left of the ecosystem, my answer establishes a lower bound. We should do this in chat, but I never know how to initiate it without making too many comments.

Comment: Alas, I am barred from chat because I [made fun of a Community Manager](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/7812/richard?tab=profile) (Ana). As far as the wider ecosystem is concerned, the world of Dredd has suffered a series of ongoing catastrophes; Atomic war, germ warfare, intentional pollution, etc etc. It's clear that the world is dying back (hence dustbowls in the Americas and Africa) but the polar regions are lush and well forested.

Comment: I don't know a lot about the Dredd universe, but I know enough to wonder how much oxygen is sequestered in gunpowder when making bullets, and how much oxygen is consumed by the firing of a bullet. Add to that the oxygen consumed by internal combustion engines, fire/flames, lamps, etc.

Comment: A far greater drain on the remaining atmospheric oxygen would be the decay of all the dead plant matter that isn't producing oxygen anymore.

Comment: @ToddWilcox As mentioned in an earlier comment, it's highly unlikely the Dredd Universe is relying on combustion (ie. burning things) for power as that would require either biomass (ie. plants) or fossil fuels to burn. There's few plants, and even if there are fossil fuels left there's no global transportation system to distribute them. As for gunpowder, it has its own oxidizer. Modern smokeless gunpowder is mostly nitrocellulose made from cellulose and acid. That would fall under "consumption of oxygen by industry" which I have no idea how to estimate in the Dredd universe.

Comment: @toddwilcox - Nuclear fission reactors  (and some forms of clean  fusion) are pretty ubiquitous throughout the world of Dredd.

Answer (score 26):

Despite the damage caused by the [Atomic Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Wars) it would appear that the world of Judge Dredd isn't quite as dead as might otherwise seem. The oxygen cycle isn't broken, nor is there any evidence that people have breathing difficulties *beyond that which you'd expect in a world that's heavily polluted.*

The Antarctic apparently hash lush jungles.

[image]

Pan-Africa still has areas of savannah (grasslands)

[image]

The Pacific ocean is still alive with fish and octopi (whose food supply would require **algae** to survive)

[image]

And they've even tried farming in the Cursed Earth, implying that microbial life is still working, despite the radiation.

[image]